# PHPCrawl: exclude urls anding with ?query=

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm playing with PHPCrawl and I'd like to know if anybody knows if it possible to exclude from crawling all the URLS with parameters (either if they are .html or .php)like

```
domain.com/article.html?showComment=1289420017718
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just foudn myself this works better

```
$crawler->addNonFollowMatch("/\?/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a non-follow match pattern for any URL containing a question mark:

`$crawler->addNonFollowMatch(".*\?.*")`

Comment: sorry but im very newbie to reg-ex: so how can I merge my previous pattern $crawler->addNonFollowMatch("/.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$/ i"); with yours?

Comment: actually strange thing is if i use your code ".*\?.*" in the test-interface it works, btu I place your code AS IS in the example it doesn't...